# Redshift - Find day wise count for the past 7 days dynamically

Tags: group-by, amazon-redshift

I am trying to build a query that would capture sales by day for the past 7 days.

Given below is what I have built:

```
select name,sale_date,count(*)
from daily_sales
where sale_date between current_date and current_date - 7
group by name,sale_date;
```

I keep getting zero records when I know there is data for this time range. Could anyone help find where I am going wrong with the above query.

Answer (score 3):

`between current_date - 7 and current_date`

the first should be the lower bound, and the second the upper bound